# video.js append html dynamically in div not working

Tags: jquery, html, video.js

I have a custom object CustomvideoObject . we drop this object in aspx page and it creates video.js related tag on fly . to achieve this i have class in app_code folder and i am using RegisterStartupScript method to register script into page. problem is that it's not adding into div on the page where i want video to render.

I have a code like this :

```
var cstext = new StringBuilder();
                     //   cstext.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\" >");
                        cstext.Append("$(document).ready(function(){");
                        cstext.Append("$(\'#movie01_div\').html(\'");
                        cstext.Append("<video id=\"");
                        cstext.Append(Vdo.FileName);
                        cstext.Append("\"");
                        cstext.Append(" runat=\"server\"");
                        cstext.Append(" class=\"video-js vjs-default-skin\"");
                        cstext.Append(" controls");
                        cstext.Append(" preload=\"Auto\"");
                        cstext.Append(" width=");
                        cstext.Append("\"");
                        cstext.Append(Vdo.VideoWidth);
                        cstext.Append("\"");
                        cstext.Append(" height=");
                        cstext.Append("\"");
                        cstext.Append(Vdo.VideoHeight);
                        cstext.Append("\"");
                        cstext.Append(" poster= ");
                        cstext.Append("\"");
                        cstext.Append(Vdo.Poster);
                        cstext.Append("\"");    
                        cstext.Append(" data-setup=\"{}\" >");
                        cstext.Append(" <source src=\"");
                        cstext.Append(Vdo.Url);
                        cstext.Append("\"");
                        cstext.Append(" type='");
                        cstext.Append(contentType);
                        cstext.Append("'");
                        cstext.Append(" />");
                        cstext.Append(" <track kind=\"captions\" src=\"");
                        cstext.Append(Vdo.CaptionsUrl);
                        cstext.Append("\"");
                        cstext.Append(" srclang=\"en\" label=\"English\" default ></track>");
                        cstext.Append(" </video>" )    ;
                       cstext.Append("')");
                       cstext.Append("});");
                     //   cstext.Append("</script>");



                        cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname, cstext.ToString(), false);
```

when i run the page, it is coming like :

```
$(document).ready(function(){$('#movie01_div').html('
      video renders fine here..
')});
```

can someone please help how i can append video in `div '#movie01_div'` . i have jquery added in head section of page.

Comment: By "video renders fine here..." do you mean you see the <video>...</video> tag there as expected? Or, even better does the video actually "render" in the `movie01_div`? You probably want to add a bit more context into who calls this etc.

Comment: yes, video is playing..tag are rendering as expected ..but it's not embedding within '#movie01_div' div. i want to render it within the div, have in aspx page not randomly anywhere..

Comment: Oh I see, ok so which div is the parent of the <video></video> tag group?

Comment: i want  'movie01_div' div to be the parent of <video></video> tag group .

Comment: I think I understand that. Which div or tag is the parent of the <video> group **now**?

Comment: it's generating dynamically , it's assigning value like 'movie01_short' that is the Vdo.FileName value I am passing in script. so i think i want something like <div id="movie01_div><div id="movie01_short"><div>....</div></div></div>

Comment: fixed..there was an error in script tag on this line cstext.Append(" type=");
                        cstext.Append(contentType);
                        cstext.Append(""); removed single '

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55025/discussion-between-sabhiram-and-ana).

Answer (score 0):

To append strings in JS, you can do the following:

```
var cstext = [
    "<div id='somediv'>",
    "    <div class='header'></div>",
    "    <div class='body'></div>",
    "    <div class='footer'></div>",
    "</div>",
].join("")
```

I think that should significantly clean up the above code so its easier to read / help go about reasoning what might be wrong here.

I am also not sure exactly about `RegisterStartupScript()` - What language are you using to emit the client response? Here is what [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1) says about this:

```
Similar to the RegisterClientScriptBlock method, the RegisterStartupScript method
emits the script just before the closing tag of the Page object's <form runat= server>
element. Be sure to include opening and closing <script> elements around the script
block string specified in the script parameter.
```